# open multiple tabs on a single window by a single click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I need to open multiple tabs on a single window, new window instance for a single link will not be a problem but when it comes to 20+ (which is my case) then 20+ new windows are really a problem, so I need to find a solution, the code has to run on chrome only in my case I have 35 links stored in an array. I am reading array using a for loop and opening links in new tabs using `window.open()`
I can use only JavaScript for this. I am developing a customized chrome extension.

I found out that while using `window.open()` to open multiple links in different tabs of a same window in Google Chrome, it succeeds in opening only first 24 windows and left out the rest.
I need to find out a way to open all the links at once with a single click.

There are some Google Chrome Extensions available which work like this like
[LinkClump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj)
This Extension successfully open all selected links in different tabs of a same window. I am trying to modify its working to suit mine.

Meanwhile, if anyone can get any solution, he/she is most welcome.

Comment: You should clarify what is the problem you're having. What happens when you open 20 windows?

Comment: I would not be very happy if website opened 20 windows all of a sudden...

Comment: @slawekwin This is not for use in a website but a [Chrome Extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/) as stated by the OP. I make use of Chrome's ability to open multiple home tabs when it opens so it's not an alien technique.

Comment: @Alasdair ah, my bad, overlooked the statement

Comment: Did either solution work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted the links to be open in a new window or not so I've included both possibilities;

#### Same Window

```
var linkArray = []; // your links
for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
    // will open each link in the current window
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: linkArray[i]
    });
}
```

[chrome.tabs documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

#### New Window

```
// will open a new window loaded with all your links
chrome.windows.create({
    url: linkArray
});
```

[chrome.windows documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

Regardless of which approach you use you will need to declare the [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#manifest) permission in your extension's manifest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `target="_blank"` attribute of a link for opening the corresponding page in new tab.

Comment: Thing is, this isn't a link thing.  The OP needs a way to do this within a script.  Unless you're talking about some hacky way of opening stuff in a new window by generating a link and programatically clicking on it...which seems like an ass-backward way to do things.

Comment: I agree with @cHao, I don't think you realize that this is a [Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) question.

Answer (score 3):

Solotion:
Use setTimeout! *With more and more time values*

```
javascript:
var a=document.location.href;
for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
    setTimeout('window.open(a)',i*200);
}
void(0);
```

This will clone the current tabs 50 times, even in Chrome! Unfortunately, in new Windows instead of new tabs. Silly Chrome :-)